# make offline leaflet map in phonegap app?

Tags: dictionary, cordova, offline, leaflet

Hi I wonder if anybody knows how to make a leaflet map offline in an phonegap app?

I´m loading the map in a div in the index page with query.load at the moment and I would like to have it working offline.

Any input appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out Silve Terra's [project](http://tech-blog.silviaterra.com/2013/02/offline-mapping-in-html5-mobile-apps.html) on offline mapping with PhoneGap and is pretty neat for storing files locally